# Create an array of NSSet having values of distinct properties of an object present in another NSArray

Tags: ios, arrays, set, nsarray, nsset

I have an array having objects with different properties. I want to create an array of sets which contain objects with same value of a single property of the object.

Suppose this is an array of object which has property a and b

```
1: {a:10, b:5}, 2: {a:2,b:5}, 3: {a:20,b:5}, 4: {a:5,b:5}, 5: {a:4,b:20}, 6: {a:51,b:20}
```

I want to create another array of `NSSet` of objects with distinct values of property b

so the result would be the following Array of 2 `NSSet`

```
1: {a:10, b:5}, {a:2,b:5}, {a:20,b:5}, {a:5,b:5}

2: {a:4,b:20}, {a:51,b:20}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this by first creating a dictionary of sets where the keys of the dictionary are the unique values of "b".

Note: This is untested code. There could be typos here.

```
NSArray *objectArray = ... // The array of "SomeObject" with the "a" and "b" values;
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (SomeObject *object in objectArray) {
    id b = object.b;
    NSMutableSet *bSet = data[b];
    if (!bSet) {
        bSet = [NSMutableSet set];
        data[b] = bSet;
    }

    [bSet addObject:object];
}

NSArray *setArray = [data allValues];
```

`setArray` will contain your array of sets.

This codes also assumes you have a sane `isEqual:` and `hash` implementation on your `SomeObject` class.

Comment: This worked like charm. Runs the loop just once so quite efficient

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this:

```
NSArray *data = @[@{@"a":@10, @"b":@5}, @{@"a":@2,@"b":@5}, @{@"a":@4,@"b":@20}, @{@"a":@51,@"b":@20}];
NSSet *bSet = [NSSet setWithArray: [data valueForKey: @"b"]];

NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: bSet.count];

for (NSNumber *bValue in bSet) {
    NSPredicate *anArrayFilterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *aDictionaryData, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        if ([aDictionaryData[@"b"] isEqual:bValue]) {
            return YES;
        }

        return NO;
    }];

    NSArray *uniqueBValueArray = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:anArrayFilterPredicate];

    [filteredArray addObject:uniqueBValueArray];
}

NSLog(@"filteredArray = %@", filteredArray);
```

Comment: FYI - 1) This is fairly inefficient. You have to process the entire array as many times as there are unique "b" values plus 1 (to get the "b" values). My solution only iterates the array once. 2) No need for `uniqueBValues`. Just iterate `bSet` in the `for` loop.

Comment: This works fine. I just tested it out, it does iterate the loop unique(b).count+1 times.

Answer (score 1):

Using Key-Value coding [collection operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577401/create-an-array-of-nsset-having-values-of-distinct-properties-of-an-object-prese), we can get the array of distinct values for an object. Then you could easily compute the results you want.

In your case this could be done like this.

```
    NSArray *arrayOfDistinctObjects = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.b"];
    NSMutableArray *newSetArray     = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (id value in arrayOfDistinctObjects) {
        NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.b == %@", value];
        NSArray *filterArray    = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSSet   *newSet         = [NSSet setWithArray:filterArray];
        [newSetArray addObject:newSet];
    }
```

where `array` is the array of objects on which you wanna operate.
`arrayOfDistinctObjects` gives you the array of distinct values for `b`.